# How do I check when the computer is being put to sleep or wakes up?

Tags: c#, power-management

I want to make my program aware of the computer being put to sleep or waking up from sleep, possibly have an event that is triggered when either of these occur. Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

void OnPowerChange(Object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) {
  switch ( e.Mode ) {
    case PowerModes.Resume: 
      ...
    case PowerModes.Suspend:
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Note this no longer works because it does not detect modern sleep.