# do something when the computer going to "sleep"

Tags: c#, sleep, power-management

How can my program do something when the computer is going to "sleep", and do something when it wakes up?  My program uses the "IPv4InterfaceStatistics" class to save ..send and receive.. Bytes 
and it saves unreal values when the computer wakes up from sleeping.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: See this [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562474/how-do-i-check-when-the-computer-is-being-put-to-sleep-or-wakes-up).  In general you should specify an operating system when asking about sleep mode.  Even if the reader assumes "Windows", which version are you targeting?

Comment: Can you add the OS you are using? This question plausably applies to Linux, Solaris, Windows, OSX, Android and iPhoneOS ( These are all platforms where System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPv4InterfaceStatistics is availible from C# )

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win API Method. It will allow your application to receive `WM_POWERBROADCAST` which you handle via your `WndProc` method.

Here's the pinvoke.net article to help you add it to your application.
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerpowersettingnotification.html