# Windows 7 catch sleep/suspend messages

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I'm wondering if it's possible to catch Windows 7 Sleep/Suspend Messages.

[Can't catch sleep/suspend messages (winXP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727154/cant-catch-sleep-suspend-messages-winxp)

Answer (score 0):

Use PInvoke to call the Win32 API RegisterPowerSettingNotification.  [Details here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerpowersettingnotification.html).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't [SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged(v=VS.100).aspx) work for you?

Best

Comment: No. At least I don't see a way to cancel it.