# What event to use in WPF to update Application after Computer was Resumed after Hibernate or Sleeping?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have WPF App, that needs to be update some data , after computer was resumed from Hibernate, or Sleep mode. Details.

If I keep Application open, and sleep computer (or hibernate) after I resume computer, I want to see Application Data updated. Without any click , or focusing..

I tried to use Application.Activated event, but it only works when I click or activate Applicaiton.

What Event Should I use?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at the [SystemEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) class. Probably [PowerModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx) will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this with the Windows APIs directl, overriding WndProc and intercepting messages:

check this one: [Can't catch sleep/suspend messages (winXP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727154/cant-catch-sleep-suspend-messages-winxp)

for example on resume from hibernation you would get **WM_POWERBROADCAST** message with **PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC** flag/parameter...