# Event to detect System wake up from sleep in C#

Tags: c#, windows, events

I need to detect the system power state mode. To be precise, I need an event which fires up when windows 7 wakes up from sleep. I am already using:

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;
```

But the problem with this event is that it is raised up four times: possibly when computer goes into sleep mode and after computer wakes up. I want an event which is raised at computer wake up only. Is there any event for this?

Comment: `PowerModeEventArgs` has a property called `Mode` that you can use to say what state its returning to

Comment: Okay .. let me try with this.... let you know :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know when Windows is going into/out of sleep or Hibernate mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228288/how-can-i-know-when-windows-is-going-into-out-of-sleep-or-hibernate-mode)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

private void OnPowerChange(object s, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    switch ( e.Mode ) 
    {
        case PowerModes.Resume: 
        break;
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
        break;
    }
}
```

You should probably read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe the event: `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged -= OnPowerChange;`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the "new" Connected/Modern Standby modes... Possible substitute in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119257/connected-standby-notification-for-a-w8-service/55676206#55676206

Comment: @ramaral at what point the even listener needs to be removed and why exactly?

Comment: @AdilMalik Because this is a static event.When an event is subscribed, the class that owns the event maintains a reference to the subscriber. As long as this reference exists the subscriber can not be collected by the garbage collector and a memory leak will occur, .

Comment: @AdilMalik The event should be unsubscribe when no longer needed or just before the subscriber is not need anymore. See [SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 11):

You need to inspect the `Mode` property of the [`PowerModeChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.powermodechangedeventargs.aspx) that is passed to the event.

From MSDN:

> - `Resume`    The operating system is about to resume from a suspended state.
> - `StatusChange`  A power mode status notification event has been raised by the operating system. This might indicate a weak or charging
>     battery, a transition between AC power and battery, or another change
>     in the status of the system power supply.
> - `Suspend`   The operating system is about to be suspended.