# Connected standby notification for a W8 Service

Tags: c++, windows, service, standby

I have a service, developed in C++ running on Windows 8 (and 8.1). How can I get to know that the system has entered Connected Standby?

Since this is a service, it does not have a window, I should be using [PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=239913), but it does not seem to be working. Does anyone know how I can get such a notification?

Comment: Same problem - no notifications when system enters connected standby. I get notifications allright when the system hibernates, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have contacted Microsoft's technical support. This is their answer:

> There are no direct notifications for ConnectedStandby enter/exit, but you can just use the monitor on/off notifications since ConnectedStandby is synonymous with screen off on an AOAC capable system (but is not on a legacy system, AOAC capability can be had by getting SystemPowerCapabilities using CallNtPowerInformation and looking at the AoAc value of the SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES struct).
>
> To get monitor on/off notifications you can use RegisterPowerSettingNotification and use the GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON power setting GUID.

Looks like there is only a workaround for this by listening to screen on/off events.

Comment: For additional reference, there's a later SDK blog giving the same answer as the tech support response: [How to get notified when going in and out of connected standby from a Windows Service?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2014/12/02/how-to-get-notified-when-going-in-and-out-of-connected-standby-from-a-windows-service/), i.e. `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` using `GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON`

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't find any offical solution of this to date. In my case detecting SessionSwitch with lock/unlock reasons was a good enough supplement:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;

...

private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                // Going into lock/standby screen
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                // Back from lock/standby
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is excruciating unable to comment!!

`CallNtPowerInformation(SystemPowerCapabilities, ...)` will return `SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES`. It has an `BOOLEAN` member `AoAc`, if it is `FALSE`, your system does not support connected standby.

It worked for me on an Intel custom hardware(same as machines in market). `AoAc` = Always On Always Connected, Intel's preference.

Comment: As @Chandrayya commented on your other answer, you need some minimum reputation in order to comment.

Comment: This method has returned me many false negatives, I wouldn't count on using it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not allowed to comment, surprise am allowed to provide answer. This not answer definitely, but discussion.

Do you not receive notification for `PBT_APMSUSPEND`, `PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND` and `PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC` in you callback?

After going through http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/26629db2-6d33-427c-a767-8c857d775079/windows-8-connected-standby-and-aoac?forum=wdk

it appears, applications need not differentiate between S3 and CS mode(a.k.a AOAC, always on, always connected.). Though it is not clear if network activity is allowed in CS.

Comment: You can able to comment once you get gained required reputations.

Comment: The callback is not called at all when the system goes to or comes from connected standby. The callback IS called with regular standby/resume.

Comment: exactly my observation.