# Getting "active" uptime from windows

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm looking for a simple way to measure the usage of windows devices, I've been looking at uptime as per below, but the issue is that it's from since it was last restarted and i want active use. For example my laptop says 22 hours because i restarted it 22 hours ago, but i wasn't using it overnight as it was in sleep mode.

```
get
        {
            using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
            {
                uptime.NextValue();       //Call this an extra time before reading its value
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "active" use? If the machine is on, it's on. Many services will be running at any time. Are you looking for the duration of interactive sessions perhaps?

Comment: The idea is we want to monitor how much active time, i.e there is a user sat using the machine instead of uptime which is just when the device was last used.

Comment: @Nathan assuming your app is always launched on the target PC, you can subscribe to sleep/wake up events and count time accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/a/18206418/8564999 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119257/connected-standby-notification-for-a-w8-service/55676206#55676206

Comment: You could also register to receive [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) notification (can use all HIDs, which includes touch screen, microphone, etc.) and reset a timer. See [GetRawInputDeviceList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist) -> [RegisterRawInputDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices). Messages are received when the application is either in foreground or background

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1765048