# Detect Windows 10 system power state

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm developing an universal windows app on Windows 10. I need to get [System Power States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx) programmatically but I can't find any solutions for that. As it's mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228288/how-can-i-know-when-windows-is-going-into-out-of-sleep-or-hibernate-mode) there is `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` but is not available in Windows 10.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: have they also removed the WMI for it?

Comment: @BugFinder I'am new in windows, I don't understund your question

Comment: @ Hans Passant the main purpose is to create an app available on PC and mobile - anyway, this functionality is needed for PC only. I really hope to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [PowerManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.power.powermanager.aspx) class in [Windows.System.Power](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.power.aspx). It provides a number of properties and events to detect the status of the device's battery and power supply. According to the documentation, this class is available in UWP as of build 10240.

Comment: this API is very poor it has only few events for battery power supply - none of `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` states...

Comment: Could you not extrapolate the status' from the available events?

Comment: This event isn't fire in windows 11 OS.